# Spark: Transforming multiple dataframes in parallel

Tags: apache-spark

Understanding how to achieve best parallelism while transforming multiple dataframes in parallel

I have an array of paths

```scala
val paths = Array("path1", "path2", .....
```

I am loading dataframe from each path then transforming and writing to destination path

```scala
paths.foreach(path => {
  val df = spark.read.parquet(path)
  df.transform(processData).write.parquet(path+"_processed")
})
```

The transformation `processData` is independent of dataframe I am loading.

This limits to processing one dataframe at a time and most of my cluster resources are idle. As processing each dataframe is independent, I converted `Array` to `ParArray` of scala.

```scala
paths.par.foreach(path => {
  val df = spark.read.parquet(path)
  df.transform(processData).write.parquet(path+"_processed")
})
```

Now it is using more resources in cluster. I am still trying to understand how it works and how to fine tune the parallel processing here

1. If I increase the default scala parallelism using `ForkJoinPool` to higher number, can it lead to more threads spawning at driver side and will be in lock state waiting for `foreach` function to finish and eventually kill the driver?
2. How does it effect the centralized spark things like `EventLoggingListnener` which needs to handle more inflow of events as multiple dataframes are processed in parallel.
3. What parameters do I consider for optimal resource utilization.
4. Any other approach

Any resources I can go through to understand this scaling would be very helpful

Comment: Do you various dataframes share the same schema?

Comment: @Oli they don't share the same schema. But the columns used for the transformation are common.

Comment: Do you have `group by` like transformations or only selects and withColumn?

Comment: Yeah there are wide transformations. `rank over partition by`

Comment: I had an idea, it may work or not depending on your transformations. Let me know :) You may need to add the `path` column in your aggregations, windowing etc...

Answer (score 4):

The reason why this is slow is that spark is very good at parallelizing computations on lots of data, stored in one big dataframe. However, it is very bad at dealing with lots of dataframes. It will start the computation on one using all its executors (even though they are not all needed) and wait for it to finish before starting the next one. This results in a lot of inactive processors. This is bad but that's not what spark was designed for.

I have a hack for you. There might need to refine it a little, but you would have the idea. Here is what I would do. From a list of paths, I would extract all the schemas of the parquet files and create a new big schema that gathers all the columns. Then, I would ask spark to read all the parquet files using this schema (the columns that are not present will be set to null automatically). I would then union all the dataframes and perform the transformation on this big dataframe and finally use `partitionBy` to store the dataframes in separate files, while still doing all of it in parallel. It would look like this.

```scala
// let create two sample datasets with one column in common (id)
// and two different columns x != y
val d1 = spark.range(3).withColumn("x", 'id * 10)
d1.show
+---+----+
| id|  x |
+---+----+
|  0|   0|
|  1|  10|
|  2|  20|
+---+----+

val d2 = spark.range(2).withColumn("y", 'id cast "string")
d2.show
+---+---+
| id|  y|
+---+---+
|  0|  0|
|  1|  1|
+---+---+

// And I store them
d1.write.parquet("hdfs:///tmp/d1.parquet")
d2.write.parquet("hdfs:///tmp/d2.parquet")
```

```scala
// Now let's create the big schema
val paths = Seq("hdfs:///tmp/d1.parquet", "hdfs:///tmp/d2.parquet")
val fields = paths
    .flatMap(path => spark.read.parquet(path).schema.fields)
    .toSet //removing duplicates
    .toArray
val big_schema = StructType(fields)

// and let's use it
val dfs = paths.map{ path => 
    spark.read
        .schema(big_schema)
        .parquet(path)
        .withColumn("path", lit(path.split("/").last))
}

// Then we are ready to create one big dataframe
dfs.reduce( _ unionAll _).show
+---+----+----+----------+
| id|   x|   y|      file|
+---+----+----+----------+
|  1|   1|null|d1.parquet|
|  2|   2|null|d1.parquet|
|  0|   0|null|d1.parquet|
|  0|null|   0|d2.parquet|
|  1|null|   1|d2.parquet|
+---+----+----+----------+
```

Yet, I do not recommend using `unionAll` on lots of dataframes. Because of spark's analysis of the execution plan, it can be very slow with many dataframes. I would use the RDD version although it is more verbose.

```scala
val rdds = sc.union(dfs.map(_.rdd))
// let's not forget to add the path to the schema
val big_df = spark.createDataFrame(rdds, 
    big_schema.add(StructField("path", StringType, true)))
transform(big_df)
    .write
    .partitionBy("path")
    .parquet("hdfs:///tmp/processed.parquet")
```

And having a look at my processed directory, I get this:

```
hdfs:///tmp/processed.parquet/_SUCCESS
hdfs:///tmp/processed.parquet/path=d1.parquet
hdfs:///tmp/processed.parquet/path=d2.parquet
```

Comment: Thanks for the approach. I liked the idea of trying to build a master dataframe and transform that instead of processing many separate dataframes. I will try to extend it for my problem.

Comment: Glad I could help. In case you have trouble, don't hesitate to ask a new question with more details about the specifics of your transformations. And if you post the link to the question here, I'll do my best to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

You should play with some variables here. Most important are: CPU cores, the size of each DF and a little use of futures. The propose is decide the priority of each DF to be processed. You can use FAIR configuration but that don't be enough and process all in parallel could consume a big part of your cluster. You have to assign priorities to DFs and use Future pooll to control the number of parallel Jobs running in your app.