# Run notebooks in parallel or run one notebook and functions in parallel?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, parallel-processing, databricks

**Scenario**: Thousands of txt/csv/parquet files sitting in a ADLS Gen 1 that needs to be checked for DQ. Some of them have millions or even billions of rows. Checks are going to be performed by a DQ package (customized) with methods inside classes.

**Requirement**: To process these DQ assessments in parallel on a Databricks cluster. In terms of performance and good practices, what would be the right approach?

1. Run notebooks (one per file) in parallel using ADF
2. Run only one notebook and parallelize the processing of those DFs inside it

Comment: are these files related to a same dataset or they are different?

Comment: They are independent, comming from different sources

Comment: @AlexOtt, your question lead me to this tread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55498998/spark-transforming-multiple-dataframes-in-parallel I think finding a way to process most of data in one big dataframe is the most favorable way, what do you think?

Comment: yes, the bigger dataframes are preferable, but it really depends on what kind of data quality is applied